# How to filter each name in column and create an email for each filtered names?

Tags: excel, vba

So I have this code which filter 1 name in the column and will send an email to the filtered user along with its data. How can I do a for next loop that will filter the other names in column A that will do the same on sending an email?

```
Sub Button1_Click()

Dim Outlook As Object
Dim Email As Object
Dim opmail As Object
Dim page As Object
Dim outApp As Object
Dim outRec As Object
Dim outAL As Object
Dim outTI As Object
Dim newSh As Worksheet
'Dim recName As String
Dim rng As Range

myFile = Application.GetOpenFilename(, , "Browse for Workbook")
If myFile = False Then Exit Sub
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(myFile)
'Set wb = ActiveSheet

wb.ActiveSheet.Range("callbackqueue[#ALL]").AutoFilter Field:=1, 
Criteria1:=Array("CALMA"), Operator:=xlAnd

'Next

 Set outApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
 Set outAL = outApp.Session.AddressLists.Item("Global Address List")
 Set outTI = outApp.CreateItem(0)


bankSID = InputBox("Enter SID")
Set outRec = outTI.Recipients.Add(bankSID)
outRec.Resolve
recName = outRec.AddressEntry.Name

'With Email
With outTI
    .To = bankSID
    .Subject = "Subject Line"
    .Body = "See assigned information below" & vbCrLf & "Regards"
    .Display

    'Set opmail = Email.GetInspector
    Set outAL = outTI.GetInspector
    Set page = outAL.WordEditor


    ActiveSheet.Range("A6:E16").Copy

    page.Application.Selection.Start = Len(.Body)
    page.Application.Selection.End = page.Application.Selection.Start
    page.Application.Selection.PasteandFormat (wdFormatPlainText)
    .Display
    .Send
    Set page = Nothing
    Set opmail = Nothing





End With

Set Email = Nothing
Set Outlook = Nothing
End Sub
```

Sorry for the question still beginning to understand VB.

Comment: Do you want to send an email for every row in your table?

Answer (score 0):

Aquinokj, if you want all the people in the named-ranged, *callbackqueue,* Then you can do a `For Each` loop. Or, you can use an InputBox to assign the value - lots of ways, just need more info... But...

Just an example:

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyStuff()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim cell As Range

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet

    For Each cell In ws.UsedRange.Columns(1).Cells
        wb.ActiveSheet.Range("callbackqueue[#ALL]").AutoFilter Field:=1, _
        Criteria1:=Array(cell.Value), Operator:=xlAnd

        'rest of code here

    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: I was trying to the for each loop which it will pass names until new name comes up to send an email notice.Sample table this are all in 1 column. It will skip sending if the same name appears on the table. until all names different names will received a notice
CALMA
CALMA
CALMA
CALMA
CALMA
CALMA
ESPENO
ESPENO
ESPENO
ESPENO
ESPENO
ESPENO
FARINAS
FARINAS
FARINAS
FARINAS
FARINAS
FARINAS
FEASTER
FEASTER
FEASTER
FEASTER
FEASTER
FEASTER
FEASTER
FEASTER
GRISIUS
GRISIUS
GRISIUS
GRISIUS
GRISIUS
MURPHY